# Deserializing JSON data from Thomson Reuters API

Tags: c#, json, wcf, soap, json.net

I need get data from this JSON file, but I'm not able to get the data using C# and Newtonsoft.  Can anyone help me to solve this issue?  The data is from the Thomson Reuters API.  I've tried other articles, but it's always a failure.

JSON:

```
{
  "RequestKey": {
    "NameType": "RIC",
    "Service": "IDN",
    "Name": "AEDMYR=R"
  },
  "QoS": {
    "TimelinessInfo": {
      "TimeInfo": 0,
      "Timeliness": "REALTIME"
    },
    "RateInfo": {
      "TimeInfo": 0,
      "Rate": "TICK_BY_TICK"
    }
  },
  "Status": {
    "StatusMsg": "OK",
    "StatusCode": 0
  },
  "Fields": {
    "Field": [
      {
        "Name": "HIGH_1",
        "DataType": "Double",
        "Double": 117.3428
      },
      {
        "Name": "LOW_1",
        "DataType": "Double",
        "Double": 117.0143
      },
      {
        "Name": "YRHIGH",
        "DataType": "Double",
        "Double": 121.8861
      },
      {
        "Name": "YRLOW",
        "DataType": "Double",
        "Double": 95.205
      },
      {
        "Name": "HIGH_TIME",
        "DataType": "Utf8String",
        "Utf8String": "03:33"
      },
      {
        "Name": "LOW_TIME",
        "DataType": "Utf8String",
        "Utf8String": "02:55"
      },
      {
        "Name": "BKGD_REF",
        "DataType": "Utf8String",
        "Utf8String": "UAEDir/MalayRgt"
      },
      {
        "Name": "GEN_TEXT16",
        "DataType": "Utf8String",
        "Utf8String": "AED vs MYR"
      },
      {
        "Name": "GV2_TEXT",
        "DataType": "Utf8String",
        "Utf8String": "AEDMYR"
      },
      {
        "Name": "VALUE_TS1",
        "DataType": "Utf8String",
        "Utf8String": "08:48:00"
      },
      {
        "Name": "VALUE_TS2",
        "DataType": "Utf8String",
        "Utf8String": "08:47:01"
      },
      {
        "Name": "VALUE_TS3",
        "DataType": "Utf8String",
        "Utf8String": "08:46:01"
      },
      {
        "Name": "MONTH_HIGH",
        "DataType": "Double",
        "Double": 118.0954
      },
      {
        "Name": "MONTH_LOW",
        "DataType": "Double",
        "Double": 114.0702
      },
      {
        "Name": "WEEK_HIGH",
        "DataType": "Double",
        "Double": 117.3428
      },
      {
        "Name": "WEEK_LOW",
        "DataType": "Double",
        "Double": 116.8654
      },
      {
        "Name": "SCALING",
        "DataType": "Utf8String",
        "Utf8String": "100"
      },
      {
        "Name": "CF_ASK",
        "DataType": "Double",
        "Double": 117.4272
      },
      {
        "Name": "CF_BID",
        "DataType": "Double",
        "Double": 117.2443
      },
      {
        "Name": "CF_CLOSE",
        "DataType": "Double",
        "Double": 116.7792
      },
      {
        "Name": "CF_DATE",
        "DataType": "Utf8String",
        "Utf8String": "23 DEC 2015"
      },
      {
        "Name": "CF_HIGH",
        "DataType": "Double",
        "Double": 117.3428
      },
      {
        "Name": "CF_LAST",
        "DataType": "Double",
        "Double": 117.2443
      },
      {
        "Name": "CF_LOW",
        "DataType": "Double",
        "Double": 117.0143
      },
      {
        "Name": "CF_NETCHNG",
        "DataType": "Double",
        "Double": 0.4651
      },
      {
        "Name": "CF_OPEN",
        "DataType": "Double",
        "Double": 116.7792
      },
      {
        "Name": "CF_SOURCE",
        "DataType": "Utf8String",
        "Utf8String": "ThomRtrs"
      },
      {
        "Name": "CF_TICK",
        "DataType": "Utf8String",
        "Utf8String": "⇧"
      },
      {
        "Name": "CF_TIME",
        "DataType": "Utf8String",
        "Utf8String": "08:48:00"
      },
      {
        "Name": "CF_NAME",
        "DataType": "Utf8String",
        "Utf8String": "UAEDir/MalayRgt"
      },
      {
        "Name": "BQOS",
        "DataType": "Utf8String",
        "Utf8String": "0"
      },
      {
        "Name": "PQOS",
        "DataType": "Utf8String",
        "Utf8String": "RT"
      },
      {
        "Name": "ConcreteService",
        "DataType": "Utf8String",
        "Utf8String": "IDN_FD3"
      },
      {
        "Name": "MSG_TYPE",
        "DataType": "Int32",
        "Int32": 0
      },
      {
        "Name": "REC_STATUS",
        "DataType": "Int32",
        "Int32": 0
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Deserialization code:

```
var result = "";
using (var objStreamReader = new StreamReader("RetrieveItem_Response_2.json"))
{
   result = objStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
JObject joResponse = JObject.Parse(result);
JArray joArray = (JArray)(joResponse["RetrieveItem_Response_2"]["ItemResponse"]);
List<Rootobject> objRootobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Rootobject>>(joArray.ToString());
```

C# Classes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Rootobject
{
    public Requestkey RequestKey { get; set; }
    public Qos QoS { get; set; }
    public Status Status { get; set; }
    public Fields Fields { get; set; }
}

public class Requestkey
{
    public string NameType { get; set; }
    public string Service { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Qos
{
    public Timelinessinfo TimelinessInfo { get; set; }
    public Rateinfo RateInfo { get; set; }
}

public class Timelinessinfo
{
    public int TimeInfo { get; set; }
    public string Timeliness { get; set; }
}

public class Rateinfo
{
    public int TimeInfo { get; set; }
    public string Rate { get; set; }
}

public class Status
{
    public string StatusMsg { get; set; }
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
}

public class Fields
{
    public Field[] Field { get; set; }
}

public class Field
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DataType { get; set; }
    public float Double { get; set; }
    public string Utf8String { get; set; }
    public int Int32 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Create a class for your JSON. Deserialize it using JSON.NET. Where are you stuck btw?

Comment: Build an `object`, then `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(...);`.

Comment: `Rootobject news = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(result );`  I have no idea why you parse it and mess with JArray *and* deserialize it.

Comment: What do you mean with "I can't able get data...", do you get an error? What happens?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have all of your classes defined correctly.  To deserialize the JSON you just need to do this:

```
Rootobject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(result);
```

You can dump out the field values like this:

```
foreach (Field f in obj.Fields.Field)
{
    string value;
    switch (f.DataType)
    {
        case "Utf8String": value = f.Utf8String; break;
        case "Double": value = f.Double.ToString(); break;
        case "Int32": value = f.Int32.ToString(); break;
        default: value = "(unknown)"; break;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(f.Name + ": " + value);
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/JD3jPD